# Adding a 'Disabled' category to dropdown list Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've got a dropdown list that is procedurally generating 'Care Items' from their category in the database, but when a care item (or it's category) is disabled I want a --Disabled-- category marker at the end of my dropdown list that then populates the disabled content.

DropDownBox

-Diet

---Dining assitance

---Food Delivery

-Hygiene

---Bathing Assistance

---Laundry

-----------Disabled------------

-Diet

---Meal Preperation

-Medicine

---Pre-Meal Pill Administration

ETC ETC

aspx:

```
<label>Care Item:</label>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsCareItems" runat="server" OnObjectCreating="odsBocaView_ObjectCreating" SelectMethod="GetCareItems" TypeName="Boca.DataView.CareData.CareConfigurationView">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="facilityId" ControlID="lstFacility" Type="Int64" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="careProgramId" ControlID="lstCareProgram" Type="Int64" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="includeDisabled" Type="Boolean" DefaultValue="False" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<qs:extendeddropdownlist id="lstCareItems" runat="server" datasourceid="odsCareItems" skinid="large" datatextfield="Name" datavaluefield="ID" datagroupfield="Category" ondatabound="OnCareItemFilterDataBound" />
```

And the cs:

```
public List<CareItemView> GetCareItems(long facilityId, long careProgramId, bool includeDisabled = true)
{
    if (facilityId > 0 && SecurityContext.RestrictedFacilityIds != null && !SecurityContext.RestrictedFacilityIds.Contains(facilityId))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var query = CareItemFactory.Instance.GetByCareProgram(facilityId, careProgramId);

    if (!includeDisabled)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => !x.IsDisabled && !x.CareItemCategory.IsDisabled);
    }
    return query.Select(i => new CareItemView
    {
        ID = i.ID,
        Category = i.CareItemCategory.Name,
        Name = i.Name
    }).ToList();
}
```

What's the best way to do this in Webforms? Can I accomplish this in my query? Yeah, I know what year it is, BTW, webforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ListItem programmatically at a given index.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(5, new ListItem() { Text = "--- Disabled ---", Value = "" });
```

The only problem is that this is done in code behind. But your source is on the aspx. So in order for this to work you need to bind the source data in code behind before you do the insertion.

You can also insert the item in your `GetCareItems` method. That would be the easiest.

```
YourList.Insert(5, new CareItemView() { Name = "--- Disabled ---" } );
```